# REGEX: Select all text between last underscore and dot

Tags: regex, string, notepad++

I'm having trouble retrieving specific information of a string.

The string is as follows:

```
20190502_PO_TEST.pdf
```

This includes the .pdf part. I need to retrieve the part between the last underscore (_) and the dot (.) leaving me with TEST

I've tried this:

```
[^_]+$
```

This however, returns:
TEST.PDF

I've also tried this:

```
_(.+)\.
```

This returns:
PO_TEST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern `[^_]+$` will match not an underscore until the end of the string and will also match the `.`

In this pattern `_(.+).` you have to escape the dot to match it literally like `_(.+)\.` see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nht414/2) and then your match will be in the first capturing group.

What you also might use:

```
^.*_\K[^.]+
```

- `^.*_` Match the last underscore
- `\K` Forget what was matched
- `[^.]+` Match 0+ times not a dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nht414/1)

Comment: For an edge case or "T_.txt", try `^.*_\K[^._]*`

Comment: @Arkadiy That might be a possibility, only that will not match anything as there is not text between the last underscore and the dot.

Comment: @Thefourthbird On the contrary,it will match the empty string between the last `_` and the `.` : `_<emptystring>.`

Comment: @Arkadiy Well, in that case the OP might use `^.*_\K[^.]*` if matching an empy string is also desired. You can remove the superfluous  `_` from the character class as you already have matched the last underscore.